# get second digit from int

Tags: java, int

I have an int that ranges from `0-99`. I need to get two separate ints, each containing one of the digits. I can't figure out how to get the second digit. (from `64` how to get the `6`) This is my code:

```
public int getNumber(int pos, boolean index){//if index = 1 - first digit, if index = 0 - second digit 
    int n;
    if(index){
        n = pos%10;
    }else{
        if(pos<10){
            n=0;
        }else{
            //????
        }
    }
    return n; 
}
```

Comment: Also you will need to initialize n as int n=0;...its not the part of answer but will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do integer division by 10. For example, in the following code `res` should equal 4:

```
int res = 42 / 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide by 10.

```
...
if(index) {
    n = pos/10;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: in order to get any leading digit; just create a loop; and during each run, divide by 10.

In your case, you can even omit the loop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
    if(index){

        return x % 10;
    }
    return x / 10;
```

or maybe a little something

```
public int getNumber(....){
    return index ? x % 10 : x / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the number by 10. If it's int, the result will be int.

```
class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 8;
        int b = 28;
        int c = 99;

        System.out.println(a / 10);
        System.out.println(b / 10);
        System.out.println(c / 10);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a trick. Replace your //???? with below code.**

```
 Integer posInt= new Integer(pos);
 n=Integer.parseInt( posInt.toString().substring(0, 1));
```

**Complete code should look like,**

```
public int getNumber(int pos, boolean index){//if index = 1 - first digit, if index = 0 - second digit 
    int n;
    if(index){
        n = pos%10;
    }else{
        if(pos<10){
            n=0;
        }else{
           Integer posInt= new Integer(pos);
           n=Integer.parseInt( posInt.toString().substring(0, 1));
        }
    }
    return n; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give a number");
int n = scan.nextInt();
int secondNumber = 0;
   while (n > 9) {
     secondNumber= n % 10;
     n /= 10;
}
```

to find the first number you need to add to while a constant = n/10; (firstNumber = n / 10;)